# Is there only one possible solution to each Flow Puzzle?

Tags: flow

Whilst I've been playing Flow for quite a while now, some of my solutions seem ridiculously convoluted.  I can't work out if there is only one solution to each puzzle or if there is sometimes more than one way to do it.  Does anyone know or can provide a specific example?

Comment: One thing I realized about the higher levels is that ALL the tiles must be used, as well.

Comment: @CanadianLuke this is the case for all levels in the game, right from pack 1 puzzle 1 :-)

Comment: Ahhh... Didn't realize till later on lol

Comment: Next logical question would be how often are there multiple solutions, perhaps even more than 2 solutions. Yea the fact that there are never empty squares does often times give you hints on what not to do, or what to do.

Comment: If you allow finger painting, you’re sure to get multiples, as the first answer shows. What about with no finger painting? (No single color path can ever be parallel adjacent with itself. (Yes you can finish the game with this rule.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the specific example I was looking for indicating that yes, **some Flow puzzles have multiple solutions**:

[image: Solution 1]
[image: Solution 2]

This is Level 136 in the 6x6 Mania pack of the base game. Both work as *perfect solutions*.

Comment: I think perfect just means you've moved each color flow just once. I often like to play by moving each color flow a little at a time meaning I often don't get perfect, unless after seeing the solution I reset then redo.

Comment: I notice that people often share solutions by not making the final square move, but you could solve, then close the overlay menu, then take a screenshot of a completed solution.

Comment: Also, very often there is enough extra space that you can move things around a little.  For example, in the left image, you can make red go up first without changing the rest of the solution.

Comment: My friends and I always played with a rule of “no finger painting”. Which means don’t fill in space by zig zagging. A more formal statement would be that one color path should never be parallel adjacent to itself. We’ve done all the levels with this rule. Both the examples above violate it. Not to say you didn’t answer the question. But I wonder if non finger paint solutions are unique. I have no examples.

Answer (score 0):

In certain levels, (In the larger boards), there are puzzles which appear to have multiple solutions. These appear more frequently in Bridge boards. (Expansion + Standalone game)

Comment: Do you know of any specific examples? I'm replaying the 9x9 bridges to find one but no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many possibilities when playing Flow. The game has an intended way of how you play. If you start to go  left, right, left and so on, it means you haven't found the proper way.

Source: I used to play Flow a lot.